# rpmbuild qemu.spec without test

Tags: qemu, rpmbuild

I am using qemu by compiling qemu.spec.

I often run the command 'rpmbuild -ba qemu.spec' because I am changing the source frequently, but it seems to take a long time to complete because of the test process.

Is there a way to disable the test process?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the tests by telling `rpmbuild` to skip the `%check` build stage:

```
rpmbuild --nocheck -ba qemu.spec
```